# MQL4 automatic stop

Tags: mql4, trading, mql

My Martingale EA should be stopped automatically if the previously manually set limit has been reached or exceeded. The last trade should expire normally and not be interrupted.

So far, I've tried the following code, without interruption, etc. the code works fine.
I also heard about RemoveExpert, but I do not know how to do it. Am grateful for any help :)

```
enum tradeD{Buy=1, Sell=2};
input tradeD   TradeType   = Buy;
input double   Initial_Lot = 0.01;
input double   Lot_Factor  = 2;
input int      Max_Spread  = 30;
input double   Pct_SL      = 0.1;  // Percentage Stop Loss
input double   Pct_TP      = 0.1;  // Percentage Take Profit
input int      Magic_Number= 73726;
input int      interrupt   = 1,0000;   
input bool     StopEA      = false;


 int OnInit()
  {
     return(INIT_SUCCEEDED);
  }
void OnDeinit(const int reason)
  {

  }
 int start()
 {
  if (StopEA == true) { return(0); } //This line will skip the execution of EA.
 }
  void OnTick()
  {
   if(OpenOrders()==0 && (SymbolInfoInteger(Symbol(),SYMBOL_SPREAD)<Max_Spread||Max_Spread==0)){
      if(TradeType==Buy){
      double flot=Initial_Lot;
      double etp=Ask+(Ask*(Pct_TP/100));
      etp=NormalizeDouble(etp,Digits);
      double esl=Ask-(Ask*(Pct_TP/100));
      esl=NormalizeDouble(esl,Digits);

      if (ask <= interrupt) { StopEA = true; return(0); }

         if(lastProfit()<0){
            flot=NormalizeDouble(lastLot()*Lot_Factor,2);
         }
        int snd=OrderSend(Symbol(),OP_BUY,flot,Ask,10,esl,etp,NULL,Magic_Number,0,clrAliceBlue); 
      }
      if(TradeType==Sell){
      double flot=Initial_Lot;
      double etp=Bid-(Bid*(Pct_TP/100));
      etp=NormalizeDouble(etp,Digits);
      double esl=Bid+(Bid*(Pct_TP/100));
      esl=NormalizeDouble(esl,Digits);

      if (bid >= interrupt) { StopEA = true; return(0); }

         if(lastProfit()<0){
            flot=NormalizeDouble(lastLot()*Lot_Factor,2);
         }
        int snd=OrderSend(Symbol(),OP_SELL,flot,Bid,10,esl,etp,NULL,Magic_Number,0,clrAliceBlue); 
      }
   }

   //checkProfit();
  }
int checkProfit(){
   int total=0;
   for(int i=OrdersTotal()+5; i >= 0; i--)
      {
      if(OrderSelect(i,SELECT_BY_POS,MODE_TRADES)){

      string ordsymB  = OrderSymbol();
      int ordtypeB    =OrderType();
      int magicnB     = OrderMagicNumber();
      int magicn=magicnB;
      double ordProfit=OrderProfit();
      int tick=OrderTicket();
      double oLots=OrderLots();

         if(ordsymB==Symbol() && magicnB==Magic_Number){
            double pctBalT=AccountBalance()*(Pct_TP/100);
            double pctBalS=AccountBalance()*(Pct_SL/100);

            if(ordProfit>=pctBalT){
               int clo=OrderClose(tick,oLots,Close[0],10,clrAntiqueWhite);
            }
            if(ordProfit<0 && MathAbs(ordProfit)>=pctBalS){
               int clo=OrderClose(tick,oLots,Close[0],10,clrAntiqueWhite);
            }
            }
         }
      }
return (total);
}

 int OpenOrders(){
   int total=0;
   for(int i=OrdersTotal()+5; i >= 0; i--)
      {
      if(OrderSelect(i,SELECT_BY_POS,MODE_TRADES)){

      string ordsymB  = OrderSymbol();
      int ordtypeB    =OrderType();
      int magicnB     = OrderMagicNumber();
      int magicn=magicnB;

         if(ordsymB==Symbol() && magicnB==Magic_Number){
            total++;
            }
         }
      }
return (total);
}


double lastProfit(){
   double total=0;
   datetime lastTime=0;
   for(int i=OrdersHistoryTotal(); i >= 0; i--)
      {
      if(OrderSelect(i,SELECT_BY_POS,MODE_HISTORY)){
      string ordSym=OrderSymbol();
      int ordType=OrderType();
      datetime ordTime=OrderOpenTime();
      double ordLot=OrderLots();
      double ordOp=OrderOpenPrice();
      int ordMag=OrderMagicNumber();
      double ordProfit=OrderProfit();

         if(ordSym==Symbol() && ordTime>lastTime && ordMag==Magic_Number){
            lastTime=ordTime;
            total=ordProfit;
         }
     }
  }
return(total);
}

double lastLot(){
   double total=0;
   datetime lastTime=0;
   for(int i=OrdersHistoryTotal(); i >= 0; i--)
      {
      if(OrderSelect(i,SELECT_BY_POS,MODE_HISTORY)){
      string ordSym=OrderSymbol();
      int ordType=OrderType();
      datetime ordTime=OrderOpenTime();
      double ordLot=OrderLots();
      double ordOp=OrderOpenPrice();
      int ordMag=OrderMagicNumber();

         if(ordSym==Symbol() && ordTime>lastTime && ordMag==Magic_Number){
            lastTime=ordTime;
            total=ordLot;
         }
     }
  }
return(total);
}
```

Comment: We are talking English here. Please translate your question into English.

Comment: sorry, first post :D

Comment: I think you need `ExpertRemove()` https://docs.mql4.com/en/common/expertremove

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   if(tick_counter>=ticks_to_close)
 {
  ExpertRemove();
  Print(TimeCurrent(),": ",__FUNCTION__," expert advisor will be unloaded");
 }
```